# Complex rule for XPO class

Tags: devexpress, xaf, xpo

I want to accomplish a simple rule for an XPO class.

The situation is as :
- I have a Vehicle class :

```
public class Vehicle : BaseObject
{
    public Vehicle(Session session)
        : base(session)
    {
    }
    public override void AfterConstruction()
    {
        base.AfterConstruction();
    }

    //...properties

    [Association, DevExpress.Xpo.Aggregated]
    public XPCollection<MeterEntry> MeterEntries
    {
        get { return GetCollection<MeterEntry>("MeterEntries"); }
    }

}
```

- And a MeterEntry class :

  public class MeterEntry : BaseObject
  {
      public MeterEntry(Session session)
          : base(session)
      {
      }
      public override void AfterConstruction()
      {
          base.AfterConstruction();
      }

  ```
  private int _MeterValue;
  private DateTime _Date;

  public int MeterValue
  {
      get
      {
          return _MeterValue;
      }

      set
      {
          SetPropertyValue("MeterValue", ref _MeterValue, value);
      }
  }

  public DateTime Date
  {
      get
      {
          return _Date;
      }

      set
      {
          SetPropertyValue("Date", ref _Date, value);
      }
  }

  [Association]
  public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
  ```

  }

I tried this Rule:

```
RuleCriteria("MeterValue >= Vehicle.MeterEntries[Date <=  xxx ].Max(MeterValue)")]
```

In the xxx I want the value of the current object's Date smtng like : TargetObject.Date but it doesn't work, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the ^ character.

```
RuleCriteria("MeterValue >= Vehicle.MeterEntries[Date <= ^.^.Date].Max(MeterValue)")]
```

See more about **Parent Relationship Traversal Operator** at: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/CustomDocument4928

Comment: I found another solution, instead of the use of ^ I used **'@This.Date'**